# :prompt for select_tag does not appear in the box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

Using this code :

```
= f.select :how_did_you_hear, HOWD_YOU_HEAR, {:prompt => "HQCard found by"}, :style => "width: 142px;"
```

The prompt is seen as blank, and the first selection is "HQCard found by". Then followed by a blank space, and the collection of items.

How can I make it appear as a default within the selection box as default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow Rails.. what a hack.

So if you use unconventionally `allow_blank` and `selected` it works :

```
= f.select :how_did_you_hear, HOWD_YOU_HEAR, { :include_blank => "HQCard found by", :selected => "HQCard found by"}, :style => "width: 142px;"
```

Answer (score 6):

Easy to use the `:include_blank`:

```
f.select :how_did_you_hear, HOWD_YOU_HEAR, :style => "width: 142px;", {:include_blank => '- Select HowD U Hear -' }
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

Comment: Nope it does the same thing. It makes it the first selection in the dropdown, but the default selection is blank.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A screenshot will help. And try `..... , {:include_blank => '- Select HowD U Hear -'}` instead?

Comment: Thanks Zabba, your answer helped combined with the `select` option.